# Is there a DirectionalLightShadow helper, or way to see the shadow's bounds?

Tags: three.js

I have a DirectionalLight with shadow working; however, it's difficult to tell where the shadow's boundaries are on the whole (it's easy to tell when I've crossed a boundary with my game character!)

Is there a way to visualize where the bounds are? A helper of some kind, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to visualize where the bounds are? A helper of some kind, perhaps?

Yes. You can visualize the shadow camera by using [CameraHelper](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/helpers/CameraHelper). Try it like so:

```js
const helper = new THREE.CameraHelper( light.shadow.camera )
scene.add( helper );
```